# Selecting the number of nearest points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, select, proximity

I have loaded a CSV file (includes points with elevation) in QGIS. I want to select exactly 1000 points in a specific area.

My idea is to select one point and then to include all nearest points to him until a threshold of 1000 points is hit.

How can I do this? Is this possible in basic QGIS or do I need a plugin first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you tagged python, here is a solution using PyQGIS:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # get features from the currently selected layer
feature = layer.selectedFeatures()[0] # only get the first feature of those that are currently selected
spatial_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures()) # build a spatial index for the layer
nearestneighbors = spatial_idx.nearestNeighbor(feature.geometry(), neighbors=1000) # build a list of the nearest 1000 neigbors
layer.selectByIds(nearestneighbors) # select the nearest neighbors
```

Answer (score 7):

Below an example of how you can do this in QGIS without using Python:

I would use the tool called ["Distance Matrix"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#distance-matrix) which comes standard with QGIS. It will return you a list of locations and you can determine the N number of nearest target points.

See the screenshots for the parameters. My workflow was as followed:

- Import your CSV file as points
- Select the point you want to use as your starting reference
- Open the Distance Matrix tool
- Input point layer as well as the target point layer are the same layer.
- For the input layer, make sure to select: selected features only
- Specify a unique `"ID"` field  (probably object `"ID"` or zone `"id"`)
- Keep default output matrix type
- Set the Nearest (k) target points to **1000**

This will produce the result you are asking for. In addition, the list provides the distance from the starting point to each individual point,  as well as the corresponding target `"ID"`. You can use this `"ID"` to join and query the original dataset if desired (for example if you would like to move over original column names).

[image: Example of Distance Matrix]

Answer (score 6):

Using only the QGIS expressions and ["Select by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression), the expression to use is:

```
/*Select the first 'n' points closest to the selected point*/
-- fid selection
with_variable (
    'selected_fid',
    array_find(
        array_agg(geom_to_wkt($geometry, 6)),
        array_agg(geom_to_wkt($geometry, 6), filter:=is_selected())[0]
        ),
    -- selection circle 
    with_variable(
        'circle', 
        make_circle(
            $geometry,
        aggregate(
            layer:=@layer_name,
            aggregate:='array_agg',
            expression:=array_max(
                            array_foreach(
                                overlay_nearest(@layer_name, $geometry,limit:=10),
                                distance($geometry,@element)
                                )
                            )
            )[@selected_fid]
        ),
    -- verify
        intersects(@circle, array_agg($geometry)[@selected_fid])
        )
    )
```

the `selected_fid` variable selects the index value of the selected geometry within the array;
the variable `circle` creates a circle with the center of the selected point and the radius equal to the furthest point within 10 points.

NB: the value of the `limit:=` argument depends on the provider:

- if shapefile: `limit:= value + 1`
- if GeoPackage: `limit:= value`

this is because `$id` starts from scratch in shapefiles

The value to be changed is the limit, for example if you want to select the first 1000 points you have to write `limit:= 1000`.

[image]