# QGIS expression not working as expected: selecting nearest neighboring points of a selected point

Tags: qgis, point, expression, select-by-expression

**The problem**

In QGIS 3.20.0 (Win 10), I have an expression that does not work as expected and I don't understand why. On a point layer, one point is selected. When using `Select by expression`, the expression should select the `N` (freely definable number) nearest neighboring points.

[Download the QGIS project with layers](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/XEdkY7s275kI05L) that show what I tried and for testing my expressions.

**What I tried**

I created an expression based on two elements (see the expressions below):

1. Get the geometry of the selected point. Check the layer `points_selection` in the project I linked to see that this works: selected points get a red ring around them. Create this as variable `@selected_point`.
2. Create a circle around each point with the radius such that it reaches to point furthest away of the `N` nearest neighbors, where `N` is the number defined in line 8 (here: `3`). Thus the circle covers all `N` neighbors.  The radius is multiplied by 1.01 to get a small buffer around the circle to be sure that the furthest points falls *within* that circle and not on its boundary. Check the layer `points_circle` in the linked project: you see that a circle is created. Create this as variable `@circle`.

As you can see in the linked project, both elements work as expected. You can also check the layer `points_line`: if you select a point, lines to the `K` nearest neighbors are drawn.

**What doesn't work**

The idea is now to combine these two elements using the expression `within (@selected_point, @circle)`, where `@selected_point` and `@circle` are the variables created with the expressions from steps 1 and 2. The `within` function should return `true` for those features (points) where the selected point (`@selected_point`, step 1) is within the circle (`@circle`) around the current feature's geometry.

**The question**

What went wrong with the expression: why doesn't it work as expected (see also screenshot at the bottom)?

**The expressions**

1. Selected Point

```
geometry (
    get_feature_by_id (
        @layer, 
        array_first( 
            aggregate(
                @layer, 
                'array_agg', 
                $id,
                filter:=is_selected( )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

2. Circle around point:

```
make_circle (
    $geometry,
    array_max(
        array_foreach (
            overlay_nearest (
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=3
            ),
            length (
                make_line (
                    $geometry, 
                    @element
                )
            )
        )
    )*1.01,
    200
)
```

3. Defining both elements as variables and stick them together with `within` - the whole expression looks like this:

```
with_variable (
    'selected_pt',
    geometry (
    get_feature_by_id (
        @layer, 
        array_first( 
            aggregate(
                @layer, 
                'array_agg', 
                $id,
                filter:=is_selected( )
            )
        )
    )
),
    with_variable (
        'circle',
        make_circle (
    $geometry,
    array_max(
        array_foreach (
            overlay_nearest (
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=9
            ),
            length (
                make_line (
                    $geometry, 
                    @element
                )
            )
        )
    )*1.01,
    200
),
        within (
            @selected_pt, 
            @circle
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: setting the limit to 9 nearest neighbors as argument of `overlay_nearest`, I here still get 12 features selected (the already selected point + 11 neighbors). As you see, there are points selected further away that are selected and others, closer, that are not selected. Both (number of points **and** which points are selected) does *not* correspond to what I expect:*
[image]

Comment: Here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411117/156712 a very similar solution to your problem that works fine.

Comment: Nice, that works perfect. So I'm still wondering where the problem is in the expression above to better understand what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression works correctly.
The problem is related to the `circle` variable which creates a circle for each point.
When we use `within (@selected_pt, @circle)`, QGIS selects all the circles that contain the selected point.
Below a screenshot that demonstrates the above, the selected point is contained only in 5 circles.

[image]